# Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 400

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

My response is :

> Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: <meta nam... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

could anyone help me please ? Thank you ! (i'm french... sorry ;)

My code is :

```
function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  DriveApp.getFiles();

  // This is the link to my spreadsheet with the Form responses and the Notification of Absence Template sheet
  // Add the link to your spreadsheet here 
  // or you can just replace the text in the link between "d/" and "/edit"
  // In my case is the text: 1Kj4U5hrIPiRAjceHkySUlLFXjckh75R-KVqn0IsNrjA
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ktAc1lf1lhQ9xf04sRm18l-8GQurW4eqnqrldbBNYj8/edit");

  // We are going to get the email address from the cell "A1" from the "Notification of Absence" sheet
  // Change the reference of the cell or the name of the sheet if it is different
  const value = ss.getSheetByName("NOA PDF").getRange("a1").getValue();
  const email = value.toString();

  // Subject of the email message
  const subject = 'Notification of Absence Form';

  // Email Text. 
  const body = "Hello Cerian,  <br/> <br/> Please find attached a Notification of Absence Form. <br/> This has also been automatically saved to the Sickness folder, but will need to be sorted into the correct employee's file. <br/> <br/> Sickness Folder - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SCPGzH4fz7ryna7SSuXSTtYbJlJ52r0U?usp=sharing.";

  // Again, the URL to your spreadsheet but now with "/export" at the end
  // Change it to the link of your spreadsheet, but leave the "/export"
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ktAc1lf1lhQ9xf04sRm18l-8GQurW4eqnqrldbBNYj8/export?';

  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + // export as pdf
    '&size=a4' + // paper size letter / You can use A4 or legal
    '&portrait=true' + // orientation portal, use false for landscape
    '&fitw=true' + // fit to page width false, to get the actual size
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + // hide optional headers and footers
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + // hide page numbers and gridlines
    '&fzr=false' + // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    '&gid=852132144'; // the sheet's Id. Change it to your sheet ID.
  // You can find the sheet ID in the link bar. 
  // Select the sheet that you want to print and check the link,
  // the gid number of the sheet is on the end of your link.
  
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  
  // Generate the PDF file
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();
  
  // Send the PDF file as an attachement 
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [{
            fileName: "Notification of Absence Form" + ".pdf",
            content: response.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    });

  // Save the PDF to Drive. The name of the PDF is going to be the name of the employee (cell b9)
  const nameFile = ss.getSheetByName("NoA PDF").getRange("b9").getValue().toString() +".pdf"
  DriveApp.createFile(response.setName(nameFile));
  var files = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
        var file = files.next();
        var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1SCPGzH4fz7ryna7SSuXSTtYbJlJ52r0U");
        destination.addFile(file);
        var pull = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
        pull.removeFile(file);   
}
}
```

Comment: this seems to be completely unrelated to the one tag you're using, [tag:performance]. Removed that tag. Please tell us what programming language this is, and what you did to make sure that your request is correct, i.e. your own debugging attempts. Also: Don't be sorry to be French, being French is not a bad thing :)

Comment: You might not have access to the file. Please tell us if you are still around.